# ListViewWebPart and new document link

Tags: web-part, list

I added a ListViewWebPart that is setup show the Shared Document list and the first view. My problem is that I do not get the New Dokument link in the web part. How do I get the web part to show the New Dokument button, using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for me the solution was to use the new XsltListView web part. Here the new item link is default when adding it in code.

Answer (score 1):

From the web part's "Verbs Menu" (arrow in top right of web part) click Modifiy This Web Part, and there should be an option somewhere to display the Toolbar. This will give you the New button, as well as Actions and Settings.

Comment: I would like to do it in code

Comment: Ah right, had a look at this? - http://jasear.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/listviewwebpart-programatically-setting-the-toolbartype-property/

Comment: I was able to sett the toolbar, but the link did not appear.